# How can I completely remove a hazelcast map from a Hazelcast cluster running externally from my applications?

Tags: external, hazelcast

I am working on a project to externalize some of our maps with an external cluster using the client/server topology provided by Hazelcast. We are using version 5.2. I want to build an endpoint or use some api provided by Hazelcast to allow me to completely remove the map in the external cluster. I don't see anywhere in the Hazelcast Management Center where you can delete maps or any API that allows me to do this.
I don't want to just evict entries I want to remove them and completely get rid of the map. I also don't want to bring the cluster down.

I have tried getting the map from the instance and calling destroy with my local external cluster and that also doesn't seem to work.

`externalHazelcastInstance.getMap("mapOfStuff").destroy();`

It will evict the entries but the map is still there.

I have found that I can enable the REST api with my NetworkConfig but there doesn't seem to be a solution there either.

Comment: What do you mean by the map being there after you call destroy? In Hazelcast, proxies will be re-created automatically if you perform any operations on them, even if you call destory beforehand. Is this the problem you are facing?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I was referring to the hazelcast management center. Once the map is there and you can see it, no api can remove it if you want to. You have to restart the cluster to get rid of it. That I couldn't do. No longer needing to do this though. Thanks for your response.